# CodeIgniter with advanced-images spark (and Phil Sturgeon's DRY methodology)

Tags: codeigniter, dry

I am having some problems getting Jens Seger's advanced-images spark. No matter what I do I cannot seem to get his image_helper to load/autoload.

My site uses [Phil Sturgeon's DRY methodology](http://philsturgeon.co.uk/blog/2010/02/CodeIgniter-Base-Classes-Keeping-it-DRY). I am wondering if this is getting in the way...

Are you meant to be able to use `application/config/autoload.php` to autoload helpers in sparks? I am autoloading the spark and have tried adding an autoload.php to the spark and using the main autoload, but to no avail.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Andy

Comment: I got it working. I had to break the spark up into it's constituent and installed it into CI the old-school way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thats not how Sparks work. You load the Spark (you can autoload that in `$autoload['sparks']` then load the helper. The spark may autoload the helper for you.